# Does playing one virus from my hand allow me to get all copies from my deck?

Tags: megaman-nt-warrior-tcg

The text on virus cards states:

> Viruses are not unique. Whenever you play a virus, you may play another copy of that virus from your deck, then shuffle your deck.

At first I assumed that playing one virus from my hand would allow me to get two total viruses, the one from my hand plus "another copy" from my deck.

Now I notice that the card says that I "play" the copy from the deck. Does that mean that each virus card I search for will itself allow me to search for another copy, potentially putting all 4 copies of the virus into play immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, playing one virus will allow you to play as many copies as you have resource slots available.

[In an article from 2004](https://web.archive.org/web/20040926002441/http://megamantcg.fanhq.com:80/Articles/Article.aspx?ID=446), Michael Reynolds, one of the game's designers, discusses the use of viruses. He directly states that viruses allow you play all copies at once, with the intention that this will enable cards with heavy color requirements.

> Viruses are resources with a twist. They are not unique, meaning you can have more than one of the same virus in play, and when you play a virus, you may play another copy of it from your deck. In this way, if you have four copies of a given virus in your deck and no resources in play – meaning you have four free resource slots – you can play all four copies when you draw and play the first.
>
> There are eight different viruses in the Grand Prix set, two for each color, all common. So you can get four copies of a color in play early in the game with only one card. This is very powerful when you consider the events and BattleChips out there that require multiples of a given color to play, like Incredible Speed from Power Up.
>
> Naturally, viruses have a drawback. Let's illustrate this with Spikey, a red virus that could help play Incredible Speed early and consistently. The drawback is how expensive it is to spend – discarding a card for an additional BattleChip play! Playing a bunch of viruses is easy, but getting further utility out of them is expensive while they occupy slots that resources with better text could occupy

Answer (score 0):

Your initial impression is correct, when you play a virus card, you may play another copy of it from the deck onto the play area (two total).  Otherwise, it would be OP to have that many resources down at once, plus the card would likely say something like you may play 'all' copies of the card when you play it, rather than 'you can play a copy, then shuffle'